# Replace block in file finds all occurrences and replaces the latest one, but the very first one is needed

Tags: replace, ansible

I have a config file and I want to replace a certain block in it, but the logic of the marker_end: "" parameter does not allow me to do what I want.

Config file:

```
# Full configuration options can be found at https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration

ui = true

#mlock = true
#disable_mlock = true

storage "file" {
  path = "/opt/vault/data"
}

#storage "consul" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
#  path    = "vault"
#}

# HTTP listener
#listener "tcp" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
#  tls_disable = 1
#}

# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.crt"
  tls_key_file  = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.key"
}

# Enterprise license_path
# This will be required for enterprise as of v1.8
#license_path = "/etc/vault.d/vault.hclic"

# Example AWS KMS auto unseal
#seal "awskms" {
#  region = "us-east-1"
#  kms_key_id = "REPLACE-ME"
#}

# Example HSM auto unseal
#seal "pkcs11" {
#  lib            = "/usr/vault/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so"
#  slot           = "0"
#  pin            = "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD"
#  key_label      = "vault-hsm-key"
#  hmac_key_label = "vault-hsm-hmac-key"
#}
```

This is the block needed to be replaced:

```
# HTTP listener
#listener "tcp" {
# address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
# tls_disable = 1
#}
```

Whith the following content:

```
# HTTP listener
listener "tcp" { 
  address = "0.0.0.0:8201"
  tls_disable = 1
}
```

But the following code:

```yaml
    - name: Disable tls for web interface
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        path: /etc/vault.d/vault.hcl
        backup: true
        marker: "{mark}"
        marker_begin: "# HTTP listener"
        marker_end: ""
        block: |
          listener "tcp" {
            address = "0.0.0.0:8201"
            tls_disable = 1
          }
```

does not work as I expected: `marker_end: ""` finds all occurrences and uses the most recent one, so the output file is:

```
# Full configuration options can be found at https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration

ui = true

#mlock = true
#disable_mlock = true

storage "file" {
  path = "/opt/vault/data"
}

#storage "consul" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
#  path    = "vault"
#}

# HTTP listener
listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8201"
  tls_disable = 1
}

# Example HSM auto unseal
#seal "pkcs11" {
#  lib            = "/usr/vault/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so"
#  slot           = "0"
#  pin            = "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD"
#  key_label      = "vault-hsm-key"
#  hmac_key_label = "vault-hsm-hmac-key"
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how [`ansible.builtin.blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) works. You cannot achieve anything reliable using an empty marker. If you want to manage your block with that module you need specific start and end markers around it. This is usually achieved by inserting the block from scratch a first time. You can then re-run the module with different content over time.

Here's an example playbook that will insert begin/end markers on your block if they don't exist using the [`ansible.builtin.replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) module in order to make it manageable in the next [`ansible.builtin.blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) task.

*Note that if you don't have a clear need of keeping that block manageable you can achieve the same result directly with [`ansible.builtin.replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html)*

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # This was my test file, just replace with yours
    file: /tmp/so_find/file/vault.hcl

  tasks:
    - name: prepare the file with block markers for later management with blockinfile if not already done
      replace:
        path: "{{ file }}"
        regexp: '^(# HTTP listener)\n(.*{[^}]*})$'
        replace: |-
          \g<1> - ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK - BEGIN
          \g<2>
          \g<1> - ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK - END

    - name: manage block with our inserted markers
      blockinfile:
        path: "{{ file }}"
        marker: "# HTTP listener - ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK - {mark}"
        backup: true
        block: |-
          listener "tcp" {
            address = "0.0.0.0:8201"
            tls_disable = 1
          }
```